how to remove the "border" around the shadcn select when the cursor is inside
I have a select which I only want a dropdown arrow and a line beneath.  I manage to remove the top/left/right borders.  Even when I dropdown the select, there is no border.  However, when the dropdown is close and the cursor is in the text, a black border shows up.
How do I remove this border ?
Thanks very much !


Try to remove ring, add class to SelectTrigger as below:
class="ring-0 focus:ring-0"

You typed focus:ring-0 twice... typo ?

You are right bro,  now updated

thanks you save me. i think its border i try border-0 border-none.

try using this on the shadcn components where you want to remove the className="ring-0 border-0 focus-visible:ring-offset-0 focus-visible:ring-0"

If you want to remove this outline in Shadcn dropdown menu. You can add the className=" focus:outline-none" to the DropdownMenuTrigger component.
